# How to combine two dataframes into one like this, using pandas and python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, logic

[Please see the picture here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLGbf.jpg)

I have two data frames and i need to convert it into single one, using merge or concat method and i am unable to do so. Can our community please help me doing this ?

Comment: Please use text to describe the tables, rather than [using an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':[1,2,2,3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':['x', 'y', 'z']})

df1.merge(df2, how='left')
```